# Handling multiple sets of projects in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I like Netbeans. More than Eclipse. More than XCode.

At work, I deal with multiple departments, each with their own set of code that is represented in Netbeans as 10-20 Projects. Since I switch between departments very frequently (multiple times a day), I currently have all of the projects open.

This kind of sucks (Open-Project-Wide search being one of my oft-used utilities).

Does anybody have any advice for dealing with these sets (switching between them quickly)?

Thanks

Comment: I know it's not entirely helpful, but Eclipse's concept of "Working Sets" is exactly this. You might see if NetBeans has something similarly named, or reevaluate Eclipse.

Comment: Googling "Netbeans Working Sets" Led me to this: http://envyandroid.com/archives/142/project-groups-in-netbeans which is EXACTLY what I was looking for :) Thanks so much. Please create an answer including this link (they're called Project Groups in Netbeans), and I'll Accept it as correct :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

NetBeans has a feature called [project groups](http://envyandroid.com/archives/142/project-groups-in-netbeans) which should provide you what you're looking for.

If you right-click on the `Projects` pane and select `Project Group`, there is a menu option called `New Project Group...` which will allow you to create a new group.

There are multiple ways to define a project group:

- You can create a "Free Group" that is either initially empty or based off of your currently open projects. You can manually add or remove projects from this group later, as needed.
- You can create a group around a "Master Project", which will include that project and all the projects that it depends upon
- You can create a group around a folder on disk, which will include any projects that NetBeans finds within that folder.

---

Eclipse has a similar feature, called "Working Sets", which provides the same functionality. I'm not sure what Xcode has to manage this, and with Visual Studio you just open a new copy for each solution you want to work with.

Comment: Visual Studio "open a new copy for each solution" is analogous to Eclipse "open a new copy for each workspace".  A difference being that a single project in VS may belong to multiple solutions, while in Eclipse a project can only belong to a single workspace (because of the directory structure restriction).  This makes shared library work in VS a little bit easier when switching solutions.

Comment: Can the same project appear in more than one project group without duplication?

Answer (score 3):

For NetBeans 8 you do as following:

- Remove any project you do not want to have in the same project group
- File > Project Groups > New Group > Choose a describing name > create the group
- Right click on the blank area in project tab and click "Project Group" > Click "none" > Select Group
- Create another project group

When you're finished creating your groups, you can right click in the blank area in project tab and click "Project Group" > Click your created project group > Select Group.